# AngularJS não acha o input

Tags: html, angularjs

Estou tentando fazer um formulário onde um campo quero que tenha no máximo 10 caracteres, porem o angular parece estar ignorando o campo, para teste mandei demonstrar na tela o valor de "$valid": segue comando abaixo:

```
<form name="formNewTask" class="form-signin" method="post" th:action="@{/saveTask}">
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="problem" class="sr-only">Problema</label>
    <div class="cols-sm-10">
        <div class="input-group">                            
            <input ng-maxlength="10"  th:value="${task.problem}" type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" name="problem" placeholder="Problema" required="required"/>                              
        </div>
    </div>
</div>  

<div class="alert alert-danger">{{formNewTask.problem.$valid}}</div>
</form>
```

Segue uma imagem abaixo de como fica o resultado de "{{formNewTask.problem.$valid}}"

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Obs 1: no console do navegador não apresenta erro.
Obs 2: essa tela já tem uma outra funcionalidade com o angular, então esta importado corretamente.

Answer (score 0):

Descobri, deve er criado um model para que ele possa ler o campo:

```
<input ng-model="tasksJS.problem" ng-maxlength="10" ng-required="true"  th:value="${task.problem}" type="text" class="form-control" id="problem" name="problem" placeholder="Problema" required="required"/>
```